# Can we Throttle SMS Sends in Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, sms, sendsmsactivity

Is it possible to throttle SMS sends in marketing cloud? 
We would like to have the ability to specify how many sms can be send from Marketing Cloud within an hour. If the threshold is hit, then sms should be queued to be sent next hour.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its possible to throttle SMS sends in Marketing Cloud. Please log a case with Marketing Cloud support and they will enable the same for you.

once it's enabled, you can see the option to throttle SMS sends. When you configure an SMS send, in the "Schedule/Activate" screen of the wizard, you can specify the how many messages can be send during a time frame (1 min, 15 min, 30 min or 1 Hour)

Screenshot below.

[image]

you can read more about throttling function in my [blog](https://sfdcleo.wordpress.com/2017/10/15/send-throttling-in-salesforce-marketing-cloud/).